# checking a selection sort method for array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, recursion

i have this method that i got from a website about selection sort that i need to check how it works :

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] data, int low, int high) {
    if (low < high) {
    swap(data, low, findMinIndex(data, low));
    selectionSort(data, low + 1, high);

    }


public static void swap(int[] array, int index1, int index2) {
    int tmp = array[index1];
    array[index1] = array[index2];
    array[index2] = tmp;
    }

    public static int findMinIndex(int[] data, int index) {
        int minIndex;
        if (index == data.length - 1)
        return index;
        minIndex = findMinIndex(data, index + 1);
        if (data[minIndex] < data[index])
        return minIndex;
        else
        return index;
        }



public static void main (String[] args) {

int[] numbers = {3, 15, 1, 9, 6, 12, 21, 17, 8}; }
```

my question is how can i run the program in the main?(whats the code to run the program)
thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem running java code through command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752485/problem-running-java-code-through-command-line)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is all in a single class:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  int[] numbers = {3, 15, 1, 9, 6, 12, 21, 17, 8};
  selectionSort(numbers, 0, 8);
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
}
```

Comment: print what? The result of the sort?

Comment: what value int high take in this method ?