# Unable to run Java unit test code from the command line

Tags: java

I'm a Java newbie. I want to run a Java Unit test on the command line and eventually run it from a PHP script. A snippet of my code follows

```
package com.src.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class First {
......
}
```

The full path to the above file on Windows is 
`D:\Users\XXX\workspace\SeleniumTest\bin\com\src\test`

When I change directories into bin and run `java com.src.test.First` I get an error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

What am I doing wrong? I've tried running `java com.src.test.First.class` and I get an error `Error: Could not find or load main class com.src.test.First.class`

Comment: If a class is not found, you have to add some classes to the classpath.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem running java code through command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752485/problem-running-java-code-through-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compile your code using the `-d` option, to specify where to place the compiled files.

If you had already done that, you need to be behind `.\com`. If you are not, you should run with the `-cp` option, showing where are your files. If you are behind `.\bin` it should look like this:

```
java -cp .\bin com.src.test.First
```

Also, you should not write the `.class` after your class name.

---

**Edit**:

When I say you need to be behind `.\something`, I mean you should be in the directory that contains the folder "something". Also, you only need to specify extra class paths with `-cp` when the directory is not in the java classpath. You could always add it to the environment variable `CLASSPATH`. More info on this subject [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

---

Comment: How can I add libraries when I'm running the program?

Comment: If you have some libraries that are not in the CLASSPATH, you could create a folder to store your libraries and add this folder to the CLASSPATH. But I suggest you code your programs in an environment like Eclipse or NetBeans.